# Pandas: rename a index label in multiindex dataframe if NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, multi-index

How can I replace the inner index label of the df below?

```
Question                                 profile_gender. Gender           
Values                                    Male     Female
Question                    Values                                  
XCS_3. Think of a problem?  NaN        25.192318  25.900784
```

to:

```
Question                                 profile_gender. Gender           
Values                                    Male     Female
Question                    Values                                  
XCS_3. Think of a problem?  Okay Done   25.192318  25.900784
```

My failed attempt:

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(['Okay Done'], 1)
```

Does nothing, doesn't even throw an error code

Comment: does `df.index.set_levels(['values','Okay Done'], 1)` work?

Comment: nope, doesn't replace the NaN. A bit odd.

Comment: This may be one to post on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have to replace the entire index which is very annoying.

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('XCS_3. Think of a problem?', ' Okay Done')],
                                     names=['Question', 'Values'])
```